# Flutter - Synchronizing Hive Data with Server

Tags: flutter, hive, synchronization

Currently, I'm coding Flutter using Hive to store data locally, and I'm unsure how to synchronize the data between Hive (which has been modified offline) and the data on the server.

Currently, I have an idea to handle this by adding boolean variables to check which data has changed, so that when there is an internet connection, I can post those data to the server. Thank you all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization is a complex subject

You can watch this CRDT implantation for Hive https://github.com/cachapa/hive_crdt

Otherwise other "offline-first" databases offer synchronization solutions

- WatermelonDB
- Couchbase Lite
- Objectbox ❤️
- PouchDB
- MongoDB Realm
- Google Firebase